# How to draw barcharts in 1 graph for totals of 4 variables?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to draw a barcharts for 4 variables in one graph.

```
YearMonth Var1 Var2 Var3 Var4  
201501    11   21   31   41  
201501    12   22   32   42  
201502    13   23   33   43  
201502    14   24   34   44  
201503    15   25   35   45  
201503    16   26   36   46
```

I want to:

1. Sum the Variables respectively by month
2. then draw bar charts for the 4 variables by month totals in one graph
3. x-axis is %Y-%m, y-axis is count
4. Different fill colors for diff variables.

I got lost in the ggplot, stat_summary and other functions....

I appreciate any help with my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get wanted results you'll need to mung your data and plot it. Package `tidyverse` will take care of that.
First you `gather` (transform) your data and group it by variable and YearMonth, then you sum per group. Finally you plot using `ggplot2`

```
library(tidyverse)
d %>%
    gather(variable, value, -YearMonth) %>%
    group_by(variable, YearMonth) %>%
    summarise(valueSum = sum(value)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(YearMonth, valueSum, fill = variable)) +
        geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge") +
        labs(x = "YearMonth",
             y = "Sum",
             main = "Sum per Year Month")
```

[image]

Comment: There is always something like "could not find function 'gather'" error. Have not completely succeed.

Comment: @HW-Scientist have you loaded newest tidyverse version?

Comment: Sure, with newest one. just tried one more time, still same notification came out. But I'm able to do the plot if I melt the data frame before the plot step......